# gcov error: Multiple sources for a single basic block

Tags: c++, xcode5, code-coverage, llvm-clang, gcov

When I invoke gcov as follows it returns the following error message:

```
gcov -a -p dynamic-maps.gcda

Multiple sources for a single basic block: <path-to-file>/dynamic-maps.cpp !=  (in _ZN16AnalysisPipeline16AnalysisServices22calculate_dynamic_mapsERKNSt3__110shared_ptrINS_6Common16AnalysisRegistryEEERKN9Utilities6ImagesERKNS3_10TimeSeriesERKNS3_14T1ParameterFitE).
Invalid .gcno File!
```

Please can someone explain what the cause of this might be.

gcov -version returns:

```
LLVM (http://llvm.org/):
  LLVM version 3.4svn
  Optimized build.
  Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
  Host CPU: core-avx-i
```

The file was compiled using Xcode 5.1 on OS X Mavericks with the following version of clang:

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: gcov works on a Mac running OS X Mountain Lion.

The version number returned is: gcov (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or 
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating Xcode to version 6.1.1 has resolved the issue.